# Performance penalty for using Array.at instead of indexing?

Tags: javascript

Given that `Array.at` is a function - Is there a performance hit for using it over normal array indexing, for positive indicies?

N.B. This is almost certainly premature optimization, but I was curious.

Answer (score 0):

I devised a test and was surprised to find that actually, yes - there is a significant difference in performance, but only in nodeJS. Firefox & Chrome showed no significant difference.

```
function testAt(arr) {
  for (let idx = 0; idx < arr.length; idx++) {
    arr.at(idx);
  }
}

function testIdx(arr) {
  for (let idx = 0; idx < arr.length; idx++) {
    arr[idx];
  }
}

let arr = [];
console.time('at');
for (let len=0;len<20000;len++) {
  testAt(arr);
  arr.push('');
}
console.timeEnd('at');

arr = [];
console.time('idx');
for (let len=0;len<20000;len++) {
  testIdx(arr);
  arr.push('');
}
console.timeEnd('idx');
```

Results:

```
NodeJS:
at: 7.246s
idx: 105.992ms

Chrome: 
at: 101.875 ms
idx: 101.848876953125 ms

Firefox: 
at: 250ms - timer ended 
idx: 170ms - timer ended
```

However, I'm not entirely convinced that my test is a good one, or that the code isn't being optimised away

Firefox: v114.0.2
Chrome: v114.0.5735.199
NodeJS: 16.17.0
OS: Win10 64 bit
i7-10700@2.9GHz, 32GB Ram

Comment: The code probably is optimised away: https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html. Also when publishing benchmark results, please at least state the version of the engines you are using (and ideally your os and hardware setup)

Comment: @Bergi. Done, Although to be honest the question is really more about should it even be a consideration - to which the answer would seem to be yes.